# Editing the file in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, file, file-io

Let's say I have some .csv file as follows:

```
1,2,5,5,
0,5,6,9,
3,2,5,7,
1,2,3,6,
```

How can I delete *','* sign at the end of each line?

**p.s.**
         For example I know how to clean a *space* at the end of the line - `file.readLine().trimmed();`, but how to do the same for other signs, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already know how to read line by line, this crude method works:

```
QString testStr = QString("1,2,5,5,");

QStringList testList = testStr.split(",");
qDebug() << "testList" << testList;

testList.removeLast();
qDebug() << "testList" << testList;

testStr = testList.join(",");
qDebug() << "testStr" << testStr;
```

// output

```
testList ("1", "2", "5", "5", "") 
testList ("1", "2", "5", "5") 
testStr "1,2,5,5"
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QTextStream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile inFile("input.csv");
    if(!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        exit(1);

    QString newFileData;
    QTextStream in(&inFile);

    //Read file line by line until it reaches the end
    while(!in.atEnd())
    {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        newFileData.append(line);

        int positionOfLastChar = newFileData.length()-1;
        char lastChar = newFileData.at(positionOfLastChar).toLatin1(); //Returns the character bevore the last character
        if(lastChar == ',')
            newFileData.remove(positionOfLastChar, //Remove at the position of the previous character 
                1                                  //one character
                );                      
        newFileData.append('\n');                  //Append the newline again, because in.readLine() ignored it
    }

    inFile.close();

    QFile outFile("output.csv");
    if(!outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate))
        exit(1);

    //Write the data to the output file
    QTextStream out(&outFile);                    
    out << newFileData;
    outFile.close();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: No problem. Please give me a few minutes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can make with another way. You can read this text `line by line` and `push.back() to vector`. And then you can call your all vector in a loop and you can delete the `last items of vectors`. And then if you want you can write your vector to txt file. After that your ',' will be deleted .

Answer (score 0):

This is another way, without storing the whole file in memory. It also shows how a console application might handle errors.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <cstdio>

QTextStream err(stderr);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    if (a.arguments().length() != 3) {
        err << "Usage: " << a.arguments()[0] << " infile outfile" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    QFile fin(a.arguments()[1]), fout(a.arguments()[2]);
    if (! fin.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        err << "Can't open input file: " << fin.fileName() << endl;
        return 2;
    }
    if (! fout.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        err << "Can't open output file: " << fout.fileName() << endl;
        return 3;
    }
    QTextStream in(&fin), out(&fout);
    while (!in.atEnd()) {
        QString line = in.readLine().trimmed();
        if (line.endsWith(",")) line.truncate(line.length()-1);
        out << line << "\n";
        if (in.status() != QTextStream::Ok) {
            err << "Error while reading." << endl;
            return 4;
        }
        if (out.status() != QTextStream::Ok) {
            err << "Error while writing." << endl;
            return 5;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```